# AS3 - Using ExernalInterface.call To Reset JS Timer

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm trying to build a 'dead mans switch' into a flash app. When the app crashes, or slows down significantly, I would like the webpage to refresh. From what I've read and seen here, it's possible to use `ExernalInterface` to call a resetTimer JS function.

Heres my AS3..

```
//External Timer and Handler
var externaltimer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
externaltimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, callTimerJS);
externaltimer.start();

function callTimerJS(event : Event):void{
  ExternalInterface.call("window.clearTimeout");
  ExternalInterface.call("timeoutHandle");

}
```

Heres my JS in my HTML page...

```
    var timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 15000);

window.clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);

timeoutHandle = window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(1);
}, 15000);
```

I'm not sure how to test this to verify it's working. I do know when I build, the webpage refreshes every 15 seconds. I'm not able to get flash to reset the timer.

Comment: It was a concept what I described back there in a comment, and it stated that three conditions should be met for the window reload to trigger. First, `ExternalInterface.available` should be true. Second, on the JS side `setTimeout` should be only called when an external interface call was first registered. And third, there are limits (unknown to me as of yet) on the function that `ExternalInterface.call()` is able to call from outside. But Andre Lehnert has provided the basics of what should be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use normal function-declarations and be sure that is not a js-core-function-name.
You can call only functions.

**AS**

```
//External Timer and Handler
var externaltimer: Timer = new Timer(1000);
externaltimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, callTimerJS);
externaltimer.start();

function callTimerJS(event : Event):void{
    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        ExternalInterface.call("clearTimeoutfromExtern");
    } 
}
```

**JS**

```
var timeoutHandle;
function clearTimeoutfromExtern(){
     clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
     timeoutHandle = setTimeout(refresh, 15000);
}
function refresh(){
    window.location.reload(1);
}
```

I just wrote it here in the editor...
Greetings.

Comment: If, for some reason, `ExternalInterface.available` would be false, this will result in unconditional reload of a webpage regardless of actual Flash performance. Also, OP says the solution should reload the webpage if Flash app stops "pinging" the JS rather than at all.

Comment: I ignored the case of `ExternalInterface.available == false` to show the basic handling. This case has to be handled.  For the second point I changed my code above to get the behavior which was asked for. Sorry.

Comment: In fact, handling the unavailability of external interface is done by not setting the timeout in the first line of your JS (or setting that timeout to something bogus, so that `clearTimeout()` won't throw an error due to null parameter).

Comment: @AndreLehnert - Just testing it. It's part of a flash project Vesper helped me with. It takes a TON of clicks and time to get the flash app to crash and I just got word that it did not work.

Comment: The premise is.. The flash app is available to users at a kiosk. Theres so many buttons (20) that play movies (20) that we have to account for someone messing around and clicking a billion times. We have a test appliance we use, with 4GB of RAM so the tests fail faster than on my macbook. Im under the impression that when flash crashes, this script will run right? Is there possibly another issue here, with firefox? If there is a memory leak will it still fire?

Comment: It is sure an issue in program the buttons and playing the movies. Try to fix this at first. Flashplayer is able to do this work (only 20 movies and buttons) without leaks. It will fire as long as the flashplayer finds a moment to fire and has not crashed completely...